# How can i give my developer his own login to my FB APP

Tags: authentication

I've got a developer who's working on my FB APP, how can i give him access? At this moment everything still has to be done through me.

Regards , Rene

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you're going to want to log in to https://developers.facebook.com/ and select the app you want to add the developer to at the top. You need to have the developer in your friends list or have their Facebook username handy.

[image: The Roles Page Location]

So click on the Roles section, and you should see a section called "Developers":

[image]

Go ahead and click "Add Developers", and you'll be able to add the developer to your app.